# Consensus for a DAG with all history of events in a peer to peer network

Tags: graph, distributed-computing, distributed-system, consensus

All nodes have to agree on a DAG that represents all events that ever occurred on the network, thus allowing to find a partial order for these events.

Links for academic papers are preferred.

(It doesn't seem complicated but I don't want to reinvent the wheel badly.)